# how to make an input column readonly while selecting some option?

Tags: javascript, html

Change input table to be "readonly" while select option matches the keyword. I just want to disable certain tabs while selecting a keyword.

script:

```
<script>
function block_SN(){
    var selects = document.querySelectorAll("select[id=select_host]");
    var serials = document.querySelectorAll("select[id=serial_number]");
    for (var index = 0; index < selects.length -1; index++) {
        if (selects[index].value.match(/keyword/))
        serials[index].readOnly = true;
    }
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input id="serial_number" name="serial_number" value="{{entry.serial_number}}" >
</div>
</td>

<td>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="select_host" name="select_host" class="selectpicker form-control" value="{{entry.hostname}}" onChange="this.form.submit();block_SN()">
        {% for entry in hosts %}
        <option value="{{entry.hostname}}">{{entry.hostname}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        <option selected="selected">{{entry.hostname}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: I see multiple issues here. By `id` when you select how do you expect multiple elements would be returned? Select by `name` or `class`attribute perhaps. Secondly, `serial_number` is an input field, then how you are querying this as a `select` field? Thirdly, how do you ensure indices of select_host and serial_number would be same? Also, would you please post a running code that shows the problem?

Answer (score 0):

querySelectorAll should be perform either on tag or class.....but here in your code your performing on id(every html tag can have unique id)....

Add class to your input and select box serial_number and select_host respectively(you can also use name based querySelectorAll).

```
    <script>
    function block_SN(){
        var selects = document.querySelectorAll(".select_host");**//changed**
        var serials = document.querySelectorAll(".serial_number");**//changed**
      for (var index = 0; index < selects.length -1; index++) {
          if (selects[index].value.match(/keyword/))
            serials[index].readOnly = true;
      }
        }
    </script>

                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input id="serial_number" class="serial_number" name="serial_number" value="{{entry.serial_number}}" ><!-- added class serial_number-->
                             </div>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                  <div class="form-group">
<!-- added class select_host -->
                                        <select class="select_host" id="select_host" name="select_host" class="selectpicker form-control" value="{{entry.hostname}}" onChange="this.form.submit();block_SN()">
                                        {% for entry in hosts %}
                                        <option value="{{entry.hostname}}">{{entry.hostname}}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        <option selected="selected">{{entry.hostname}}</option>
                                      </select>
                                  </div>
                              </td>
```

Comment: thank you for answer my question. but I think "querySelectorAll" work for id and iterate all input in my form. as I used it for many time. the only problem I thought is the "serials[index]" attribute may not support set to readonly.

Comment: @The_flash querySelectorAll will work but every html page should have only one 1 id(unqiue id form every element). In that case you can use queryselector instead querySelectorAll

Comment: Opps, sorry, there's some HTML code, I didn't show up here, there loop entry in the form that same like "hosts" , which means there's multiple serial_number I need to get and change.

Answer (score 0):

**For this HTML Code is like:**

```
<select id="sel_id">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
</select>
<input type = "text" id = "text1" />
```

**And JS Code is like this:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sel_id").change(function () {
        var x = $(this).val();

        alert("Selected Option other than Three. Input Box is still not Disabled");
        alert($(this).val());

        if (x == "three") {

            alert("Selected Option Three. Input Box is now Disabled");
            $(text1).attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

**Here, When the "Three" Option from select is selected then only Input TextBox is disabled.**

***Update 1:*** **Use onchange="myFunction()" Event on select to get realtime change in Textbox.**